# extract jsonarray from xml string

Tags: android, json, xml, http-post

I'm trying to call a url link via http post method by using asynctask. I'm passing parameters to the like if the link is "http://example.com/broadcast/" I'm adding "name=ravi/age=30/" parameters like this. The operation is working as the output is obtained but the response I'm getting is in xml string format which contains JSONArray. I just want to extract the JSONArray output from xml string.

```css
webResponse output:

<?xml version="1.0"  
encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="https://example.com/statement">

[{"status":"ok","code":"pass"}]</string>
```

```html
public class HttpPostExample extends Activity {

 
 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_http_post_example);
        
    Button saveme=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    saveme.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
         public void onClick(View v){
          
           
          new AsyncCallWS().execute();
          
         }
     });  
  } //oncreate
    
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
     
     
     
  @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            
      

        }

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   String webResponse=""; 
   
   HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/going.asmx/broadcast?"); 

   //Post Data
   List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
   nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alpha", "A1B2C3"));
   nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "IN"));
   nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Somnath"));
   nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bind", "Hour Glass"));
   nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("body", "Hundo"));

   //Encoding POST data
   try{
     httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
   }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
 
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e);
   }

   //making POST request.
   try{
     HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
     webResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    
     
     
   }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // Log exception
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e);
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // Log exception
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e);
   } catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

  
       
   return  webResponse;
  }
  
   @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String webResponse) {
          
      
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), webResponse, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
      
    } // AsyncTask ends
    
    
 

} //activity
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to remove the xml code by below code and get the json array from that in postExecute:

```
    int first,second;
    first = webResponse.indexOf("[");
    second = webResponse.indexOf(first +1 , webResponse.length());
    String json = webResponse.substring(first, second);
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray array = jsonObj.getJSONArray("status");
```

Comment: for getting data from that array chek link below
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: where does "jsonStr" comes from? Its giving "cannot resolved to a variable error".

Comment: I tried it like this to get atleast [{"status":"ok", "code":"pass"}], but got error "Error while executing doInBackground" and "Caused by:StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=126, regionStart=86, regionLength=-87

Comment: The code used is: `HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
     
     String temp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
     
     int first,second;
        first = temp.indexOf("[");
        second = temp.indexOf(first +1 , temp.length());
        webResponse = temp.substring(first, second);`

Then I use Toast in onPostExecute to display webResponse.

Comment: @sam , use the code that i suggested , i think it must work. i edited it , and remove the "jsonStr"  from that.

Comment: Still getting the same "StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=126, regionStart=86, regionLength=-87" error

Comment: Thanks Pirisok. I tried your method with my own logic and obtained the result.

Comment: nice , glad that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the required result using the below code:

```html
   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    String XmlString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    XmlString=XmlString.replaceAll("\\<\\?xml(.+?)\\?\\>", "").trim();
    XmlString = XmlString.substring(XmlString.indexOf("[") + 1, XmlString.lastIndexOf("]"));
    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(XmlString);
    webResponse = jObj.getString("status");
```